# What is the equivalent of $on("$ionicView.beforeEnter") for Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

What is the equivalent of $on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function() {}) for Ionic 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are now different view lifecyle hooks like onPageWillLeave() or onPageWillEnter(). Use this as a 
[reference](https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/)

With ionic beta 8 the lifecylcle events changed their names. Check out the [official ionic blog](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-beta-8-is-live/) for the full list of the lifecycle events.